# Cannot read property 'Nome"' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing an exercise using Asp.Net Core Web API and Angular 7 CRUD, but having some trouble when the input receives the property.

I'd already checked the Database Columns, and the name isn't wrong. And checked the services too.

```html
    <input name="CardOwner" #CardOwner="ngModel"[(ngModel)]="service.formData.CardOwner" 
    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CardOwner" required maxlength="100">
```

```
export class PaymentDetail {
    PMId: number= 0;
    CardOwner: string= "";
    CardNumber: string= "";
    ExpirationDate: string= "";
    CVV: string= "";
}
```

```
 public class PaymentDetails
    {   
        [Key]
        public int PMId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(100)")]
        public String CardOwner { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(16)")]
        public String CardNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(5)")]
        public String ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(3)")]
        public String CVV { get; set;}
    }
```

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CardOwner' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (PaymentDetailComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
```

Comment: i can only imagine it's async data you are getting there, so you should use the safe navigation operator: `[ngModel]="service.formData?.CardOwner"`

Comment: , I've removed the .formData. and had worked, thanks for the answer

Comment: But, the service isn't working

Comment: in your title you mentioned "Nome" is it typo or this is what exactly you get?

Comment: Sorry dude, I`d posted this at the BR Stackoverflow too. I've forgotten to change the Nome to Name, is just a simple Typo